# Adding simple cart functions to button in Android suite

Tags: java, android, shopping-cart

I am creating a simple department store app for a class, and have a functioning main screen and screens for "products".  I added a plus button next to each product, now I need Android to push the product data to a cart screen if that button is pushed.  I feel like this has to be simpler than I am making it...  Here is the screen shot of the java file for one of my products screen...
[Products screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLU9S.png)

Here is the screenshot of cart.java
[Cart screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghIMe.png)

Any help you can give me with this is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: what is the problem you getting?

Comment: why don't you paste the code instead of taking screenshot of it?

Comment: I thought the screenshot would show up in the post, but I am new so it won't.

Comment: The problem is the button is not wokring at all.  No errors, just not working in the app.  The button is not adding the product to the cart.  I am missing a piece, but I don't see it. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.androiddom.com/2011/02/android-shopping-cart-tutorial.html

Comment: I did everything in the tutorials and my app keeps crashing. I checked in with my professor and we found the problem. Thanks everyone!